# Accessing a Flask app as computer name on local network

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

#### My Setup

Ubuntu 14.04 with lts nginx webserver using gunicorn for flask app.

#### Question

How do I get my flask app http available as my computer name which is 'argonaut'?

For example, I want the behavior I get when I use the flask webserver in which my app is accessed using

```
 http://argonaut:8080
 http://localhost:8080,
 http://0.0.0.0:8080, or
 http://127.0.0.1
```

#### Problem

When I go through gunicorn and nginx, it is only available through localhost, 127.0.0.1

#### My effort

I've edited my config files to death, and I've only managed to break the app.
**nginx config**(please be kind, I've read the docs and am very confused)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name argonaut;

    root /hello;

    access_log /logs/access.log;
    error_log /logs/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I set server to 'argonaut' which is my computer name.

I start gunicorn with `unicorn hello:app`.

#### flask application hello.py

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Helloo world!"

app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

#### My /etc/hosts file

```
chet@argonaut:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   argonaut

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add your hostname to the 127.0.0.1 line in your /etc/hosts file.  Notice that right now, it's on the 127.0.1.1 line.  Ubuntu does this for some reason.

See also: https://serverfault.com/q/363095/179471